# python 3. Stop sorting alphabetically keys in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to get a list of keys from a dict but I want to preserve the original order of keys in dict.

For example:

```
import collections
g = {'a' : '1',
     'c' : '3',
     'd' : '4',
     'b' : '2'}
```

when i run `g` I get: `{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4'}`

when i run `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(g).keys()` I get: `odict_keys(['b', 'd', 'a', 'c'])`

when i run `list( collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(g).keys() )` I get: `['b', 'd', 'a', 'c']`

Anybody knows how can I get the initial order, which is: `['a', 'c', 'd', 'b']`

Comment: You can't, dictionaries aren't ordered data structures and that initial order is lost. If you want it ordered, *start with an `OrderedDict`*.

Comment: thanks, @jonrsharpe